# Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, software-installation, opencv, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I'm trying to install opencv on a raspberryPI 4 (RaspberryPI OS Bullseye x64, Python 9), that is part of installing all the dependencies for [this tutorial](https://github.com/pythonlessons/TensorFlow-2.x-YOLOv3) but it always fails with the error below.

I tried to install all the dependencies from the requirements list one by one and replaced the opencv-python library with opencv-contrib-python which succeeded to install and was quite quick.

The opencv-python library fails to install and takes VERY long. So I have two main questions:

1 - why is this error happening and how to fix it?

2 - is fixing and installing opencv that way (some sources say that it takes 4h) really makes a difference?

```
    -- Installing: /tmp/pip-install-e57iq6sc/opencv-python_02151bbb64874ba69626df8ef3e9b5e4/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_frontalface_improved.xml
  -- Installing: /tmp/pip-install-e57iq6sc/opencv-python_02151bbb64874ba69626df8ef3e9b5e4/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_profileface.xml
  -- Installing: /tmp/pip-install-e57iq6sc/opencv-python_02151bbb64874ba69626df8ef3e9b5e4/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/lbpcascades/lbpcascade_silverware.xml
  
  
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  
  
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Unix Makefiles" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Unix Makefiles" generator - success
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  Configuring Project
    Working directory:
      /tmp/pip-install-e57iq6sc/opencv-python_02151bbb64874ba69626df8ef3e9b5e4/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-build
    Command:
      cmake /tmp/pip-install-e57iq6sc/opencv-python_02151bbb64874ba69626df8ef3e9b5e4/opencv -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/tmp/pip-install-e57iq6sc/opencv-python_02151bbb64874ba69626df8ef3e9b5e4/_skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install -DPYTHON_VERSION_STRING:STRING=3.9.2 -DSKBUILD:INTERNAL=TRUE -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=/tmp/pip-build-env-4ll879y8/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/resources/cmake -DPython3_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python3 -DPython3_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python3.9 -DPython3_LIBRARY:PATH=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.so -DPython3_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=/tmp/pip-build-env-4ll879y8/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -DPython_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python3 -DPython_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python3.9 -DPython_LIBRARY:PATH=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.so -DPython_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=/tmp/pip-build-env-4ll879y8/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python3.9 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY:PATH=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.so -DPYTHON_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=/tmp/pip-build-env-4ll879y8/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.9 -DPYTHON3_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.so -DBUILD_opencv_python3=ON -DBUILD_opencv_python2=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF -DOPENCV_SKIP_PYTHON_LOADER=ON -DOPENCV_PYTHON3_INSTALL_PATH=python -DINSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB=ON -DBUILD_opencv_apps=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release
  
  Copying files from CMake output
  creating directory _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/python/cv2.cpython-39-aarch64-linux-gnu.so -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/cv2.cpython-39-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
  creating directory _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_eye.xml
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalcatface_extended.xml -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalcatface_extended.xml
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_fullbody.xml -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_fullbody.xml
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_licence_plate_rus_16stages.xml -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_licence_plate_rus_16stages.xml
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_lowerbody.xml -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_lowerbody.xml
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_profileface.xml -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_profileface.xml
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_russian_plate_number.xml -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_russian_plate_number.xml
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_smile.xml -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_smile.xml
  copying _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_upperbody.xml -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/data/haarcascade_upperbody.xml
  Copying files from non-default sourcetree locations
  copying LICENSE.txt -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/LICENSE.txt
  copying LICENSE-3RD-PARTY.txt -> _skbuild/linux-aarch64-3.9/cmake-install/cv2/LICENSE-3RD-PARTY.txt
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/tmpj_ba5nbz_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "/tmp/tmpj_ba5nbz_in_process.py", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/tmp/tmpj_ba5nbz_in_process.py", line 204, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 412, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 397, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 483, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 452, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 212, in main
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4ll879y8/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 676, in setup
      _classify_installed_files(
    File "<string>", line 392, in _classify_installed_files_override
  TypeError: _classify_installed_files() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cmake_install_dir'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
Failed to build opencv-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: What reasons do you have for not using the version of opencv which comes as standard?

Comment: I'm newbie with Raspberry, so I don't really know. I just launched the pip install requirements and it started that crazy long compile process and failed. Then I installed all by hand and it worked. But I wan't to know what is the difference and why is this happening.

Answer (score 1):

The   Raspberry Pi OS  is  based  on  Debian.

The  Debian maintainers spend a lot of effort  to  ensure that all  the bundled packages, libraries, and utilities work properly   together.

When you introduce out of  stream software you break all that effort.  In an attempt to update packages,  libraries, and utilities to be compatible with the new software all sorts of other dependencies may be  broken.

Comment: This doesn't answer any of my questions.